# create an animation of a string

Tags: plotting, manipulate, physics, animation

I'm trying to create an animation of motion of a physical string, it should demonstrate a "jumping rope", but I don't know what function to use, I've tried parametric plot and vector plot. I would like help, this is new to me.

The vector of the string is

```
    x[t, \[Sigma]] = {Sin[\[Pi]/4]*Cos[\[Pi]*t/3]*Sin[\[Pi]*\[Sigma]], 
  Sin[\[Pi]/4]*Sin[\[Pi]*t/3]*Sin[\[Pi]*\[Sigma]], \[Sigma]*
   Cos[\[Pi]/4]}
```

Iv tried

```
ParametricPlot3DPlot3D[{Sin[\[Pi]/4]*Cos[\[Pi]*t/3]*
   Sin[\[Pi]*\[Sigma]], 
  Sin[\[Pi]/4]*Sin[\[Pi]*t/3]*Sin[\[Pi]*\[Sigma]], \[Sigma]*
   Cos[\[Pi]/4]}, {t, 0, 2}, {\[Sigma], 0, 2}]
```

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. If this is a homework question, please add a homework tag. Also include Mathematica code for what you have tried out so far. The code that you have currently included has nothing to do with strings.

Comment: @Syed I think the author of the OP means by a string not the Mathematica string, but rather the jumping rope as they have described. Perhaps the tag `string-manipulation` has to be removed.

Comment: It may be so. Let the OP clarify it; preferably with some working code.

Comment: First attend to your code. You need to use patterns to define your function x: `x[t_, s_] = ...` or `x[t_, s_] := ...` (I'm using English letters for clarity). And your ParemetricPlot3D is misspelled (extra Plot3D tacked on). So, you can plot like this: `ParametricPlot3D[x[t, s], {t, 0, 2}, {s, 0, 2}]`. To plot one "instant" you can do: `ParametricPlot3D[x[t, s], {s, 0, 2}]` for some fixed t. To animate, you can make that t the operative variable in Animate: `Animate[ParametricPlot3D[x[t, s], {s, 0, 2}], {t, 0, 2}]`. And from there you'll need to fix up the visualization to your liking.

Comment: thank you, this was helpful, I did write

```
Animate[ParametricPlot3D[X[t, \[Sigma]], {\[Sigma], 0, 2}], {t, 0, 5}]
```
but I want the z axis to be in the middle, and another problem is that all axes are moving in the animation, I want them to stay fixed

Comment: https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/TheVibratingString/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After correction of some syntax errors:

```
x[t_, \[Sigma]_] = {Sin[\[Pi]/4]*Cos[\[Pi]*t/3]*Sin[\[Pi]*\[Sigma]], 
   Sin[\[Pi]/4]*Sin[\[Pi]*t/3]*Sin[\[Pi]*\[Sigma]], \[Sigma]*
    Cos[\[Pi]/4]};
Animate[ParametricPlot3D[x[t, \[Sigma]], {\[Sigma], 0, 2}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {0, 2}}], {t, 0, 5}]
```

[image]